# UINavigationController containing a UITableView, then a UITabBarController with more UITableView's

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

Sorry for the vague title!

I am trying to achieve the following functionality: A user is first presented with a UINavigationController containing a UITableView. When the user taps a cell in the table view, I want to push a new view which contains a UITabBarController (**that'll stay visible regardless of the currently visible UIViewController**) and a UITableView again, that people can again select a cell from and which will then again push to UINavigationController.

If a user selects a tab from the UITabBar, I want the first screen (without the UITabBar) to be the one that users can go back to, not the tab they just came from. Also, if a user selects one of the UITableView items on any of the tabs, I want the back button to go back to the previously displayed screen (as you'd expect with a standard UINavigationController)

I've spent hours trying to find the answer to this and I just can't anywhere! I hope I haven't been too vague or confusing in my explanation.

James.

Answer (score 1):

If your desired UX is confusing to explain here, imagine how your users will feel! I would reconsider the intended design.

From the View Controller Programming Guide:

> An application that uses a tab bar controller can also use navigation
>   controllers in one or more tabs. When combining these two types of
>   view controller in the same user interface, the tab bar controller
>   always acts as the wrapper for the navigation controllers. You never
>   want to push a tab bar controller onto the navigation stack of a
>   navigation controller. Doing so creates an unusual situation whereby
>   the tab bar appears only while a specific view controller is at the
>   top of the navigation stack. Tab bars are designed to be persistent,
>   and so this transient approach can be confusing to users.

That said, you can probably hack something close to what you are talking about but you'll need to write a bunch of code to handle the navigation using the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate` methods and keep track of whatever state you need to know where you want to navigate to based on a user action. Odds are you'll end up with something complicated to code, maintain, and worse, use.

Comment: Thanks. I ended out changing the view so the UITabBar is always on display, and the first screen I was speaking of is instead presented as a modal view when the user first launches the app (it is to select a shopping basket for the user to work on in the other views)